# Extracting wordpress blog posts from database

Tags: php, wordpress

I am struggling to export the blog posts of my local wordpress site to a pdf file.
In other words, having all the posts that I have written separately to be merged in one single file such as pdf, doc, or any other format ...

I tried to do this myself, by  creating a custom plugin, but I didn't succeed to retrieve posts, so I tried to do it directly with standard php using none of wordpress classes and placed the file under the root folder of the local website not in the plugin folder, and here is my code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "scienceted";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$querystr = "
SELECT wp_posts.post_title as Title, wp_posts.post_date as DATE,
  GROUP_CONCAT(wp_terms.name) AS TAGS, wp_posts.post_content as CONTENT FROM wp_terms
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
  WHERE post_author = 0 AND post_type LIKE 'post' AND post_status LIKE 'publish' GROUP BY wp_posts.ID order by post_date\G
";
$result = $conn->query($querystr);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: ";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

and I get this result:
[image]

Line 23 is this : `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {`

If this step is done correctly then I can group posts by category.

Comment: You might mention what line is 23?  it looks like its the query() line, but looking at the line after that, you use a potential property, num_rows, check if thats it, and the line after fetch_assoc  make sure those are available, i.e did your result string build correctly?  just before your if condidion, `var_dump($result)`, and look at it. .  

also, you can take the php tags out for the demo i believe, theya re crooked anyway. hehe

Comment: I removed all the inner joins to make it work using this query `SELECT wp_posts.post_title as Title, wp_posts.post_content as Content FROM wp_posts`. As you can see, I worked on `wp_posts` only I need to retrieve Categories from `wp_terms`.

Comment: ahh so your having a join issue then?  if so, then make sure you have adjusted your title, this is nothing to do with pdf then.   '$result = $conn->query($querystr);' can you put the var_dup after that line?  i want to see whats result, it must be an error, if it is, then you have query issue, and need to readjust your question, title, and tags as soon as possible before somebody else tried to help and gets frustrated, or its downvoted :-)

Comment: I could extract all the posts  but not by category, I changed the title, but the main goal is extracting this result to pdf, maybe in other question if couldn't do it myself. Thanks for you guiding @BrianThomas .

Comment: 3rd time, asking for a `var_dump`, is that possible?  If you simple put one after this line like this `$result = $conn->query($querystr); var_dump($result); exit;` will tell you alot about whats going on, then when you get those results, update the original post with that code snippet please. If your having a join issue for sure, and you know that, the word extracting, and wordpress, blog, and post in the title are kind of misleading to the issue no?  Isnt the isue more like `db join on wp issue`? You decide, totally up to you, just trying to help you resolve. .  nobody else helping yet?